# cast mongodb query result to data model class in java

Tags: java, mongodb, model

I want to create a data model of java class, so that I can automatically get some Properties of the data Model which retrieved from the dbcollection of mongodb by using method defined in the class.
 Let's say if I have a data structure stored in mongodb collection named "STUDENT" like:

```
{
   "name":"Jone",
   "id":"20140314201"
   "courses":[
        {
           "CourseName":"math",
           "teacher":"Prof Smith",
           "Score":80
        },
        {
           "CourseName":"literature",
           "teacher":"Brown"
           "Score":58
        }
   ]
}
```

It's always convenient to define a student class like this:

```
class Student extends BasicDBObject{
     private List<Course> courseList = new ArrayList();
     private final String name;
     private final String id;

     public Student(String _name,String _id){
         name = _name;
         id = _id;
     }
     public List<Course> getFailedCourseList(){
        List<Course> failedCouseList = blablabla...
        return failedCouseList
     }
     public addCourse(Course _course){
          couseList.add(_cousrse);
     }
     .....
}
```

The question is can I just do some job to make these  happen:
1. when saving a STUDENT items into mongodb I can just do this:

```
Student studentItem = new Student("Jone","20140314201")
studentItem.addCourse(course1) 
studentItem.addCourse(course2)
....
DBC.save(studentItem)
```

2. when retrieve data from db collection I can just cast BasicDBObject(which is the default object type dbcollection `findOne` returned) to `Class Student` I defined:

```
Student studentJone = (Student)DBC.findOne(new BasicDBObject("name":"Jone"));
```

so that I can just find Out what courses failed by just invoke a method of the Student class:

```
List<Course> failedCourseList = studentJone.getFailedCourseList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
BasicDBObject query= new BasicDBObject();
query.put("any key","any value"); //THis add criteria
DBObject dbObjectResult = getMongoTemplate().getCollection(COLLECTION)
                    .findOne(query);
Foo foo = getMongoTemplate().getConverter().read(Foo.class, dbObjectResult);
```

Should be work

Comment: what is getMongoTemplate() here

Comment: @ChitKhine MongoTemplate is the object used to connect, persist, get or update data using Spring Data (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html )

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can

Please see this url : http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-java-dbobject-to-perform-saves/

Comment: Oops, I think the link has died, it redirects to a default doc page